# Possible reputation bug?

Tags: support

I downvoted an answer, and was surprised to see it show up in *my own* reputation history. I don't think I've ever noticed this happening on other Stack Exchange sites. The 1 point isn't important to me, but I thought it might be a bug. I didn't think up/downvotes affected the person doing the voting, or showed up in the voter's reputation history.

Or maybe my downvote was downvoted because I didn't add a comment with a reason. (Other people had already done so, and I didn't have anything else to add.)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downvoting *questions* doesn't cost any rep, but downvoting *answers* costs a single rep point. The point of this almost-negligible penalty is to give people pause before going on downvote sprees. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Also worth noting is that while the rep change shows up in your history, it only shows up in it when you look at it yourself, so others cannot use this to see who downvoted them.